# CSS content will not wrap multiple divs

Tags: html, css

OK this is fairly complicated to explain so I've put it online here:

http://jsfiddle.net/zSgPr/10/

I need the yellow container to wrap around the lower brown div and red footer div in this set-up, leaving the footer at the bottom of the page, ideally where I can then adjust it by pixel margins. I have tried multiple ways of clearing it with some luck, however I can't figure out how to get the footer to behave or the content to encapsulate properly. Could somebody suggest a means of doing it? Thanks guys.

This is what I am trying to achieve

[image: http://i.imgur.com/PqO44.png]

Answer:

Was overlooking the obvious that I needed another container div. If anyone wants to see it's on-line here: http://jsfiddle.net/zSgPr/21/

Comment: Can you "draw" your expected output? Because you've named your red `DIV` "footer", but it doesn't seem like a general-meaning "footer" (while the black or the brown one does).

Comment: HI @idb YOu want this http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/zSgPr/16/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `bottom:0` to `.textbox`

Plcace the `.textbox` div outside the container which means when you are giving `position:absolute` the parent div should have `Position:relative` so add relative to main div which is `.page`

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zSgPr/19/)**

**[SOLUTION](http://jsfiddle.net/zSgPr/21/)**

Answer (score 0):

Change .textbox style like this mayble helpful

```
.textbox{
    margin:0px 10px; 
    background-color:#262626; 
    width:700px;        
    position:relative;
    z-index:40;
    border:2px dashed #381e01;
    float:left;
 }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zSgPr/20/)